# Run application in login window

Tags: windows-7, macos, start-screen, login-screen, airplay

I am looking for a way to run an application like Reflector or AirServer on both a Mac and PC before the user login occurs, the application is pretty much GUI-less until someone starts sending data to it, at which point it goes full screen.

*Is there a way to run an application in the Login screen on a Mac and/or PC?*

Answer (score 2):

In OS X you can create a pre-login launchd agent. For example save this property list as `/Library/LaunchAgents/some.label.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>some.label</string>
  <key>LimitLoadToSessionType</key>
  <array>
    <string>LoginWindow</string>
    <string>Aqua</string>
  </array>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>say</string>
    <string>a</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Make sure the plist is owned by root. If it is not, it can be loaded if you run `launchd load` as the user but it is not loaded by launchd automatically.

Then if you restart, the say command should be run once when the login window is shown and again after a user logs in graphically.

If you don't want the program to be run again when a user logs in graphically, remove `<string>Aqua</string>`.

If automatic login is enabled and `LimitLoadToSessionType` is set to just `LoginWindow`, the program is not run at all.

See the [Daemons and Agents tech note](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2083/_index.html) or `man launchd.plist` for more information.